# Do reviews get compared to the previous / accepted review in the queue or the original question / answer?

Tags: discussion

The reason for this question is that my edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107616/results-mismatch) was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14019150).

I went to see why and it looks like my changes are being compared to something other than the original question. When I made my edit it was to the original question and I  edited the code so that the braces were in the correct place and the code was generally formatted better. However, I made no changes to the text (probably should've done). This was put into a queue of changes.

Now my change looks like I did nothing with the code and actually suggested reverting the text of the question back to the original rather than keep some slightly better formatting. I can only guess that the accepted edit did the same code change as well as the text change. If that's the case then it looks like my edits are poor quality rather simply missing some additional changes.

Is this how it works?

Comment: From the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40107616/revisions) you can see that two users with >2k reputation edited the question, obviously while your suggested edit was pending. This can happen, but usually doesn't happen very often. As long as you don't get banned, just don't worry ;)

Comment: @honk - this sounds like this kind of thing could happen quite a lot. A question with a few formatting issues is quite common, so my guess would be that someone could easily miss a couple where someone else didn't (like me). Would it not be better to compare against the original alongside the latest change? That way there could be an option such as 'Rejected - superceded by an earlier edit'.

Comment: What you suggest would make reviewing more complicated. I don't think that this would be implemented. And basically it doesn't matter why your edit gets rejected (apart from your personal feeling). It's just important that a conflicting edit gets rejected. As I said before: Just don't worry.